# Add custom UIActivity for standard apps

Tags: ios, uiactivity

dear community,

A simple question but no clear answer yet.

Can I add my button to standard UIActivityController so that when user goes to Photos/Notes/Safari he can also along with twitter/facebook post it to my destination ?

[image: Activity controller for photos app]

I'm sure I can do that while calling UIActivityViewController from within my app. 
And looks like there is a way to do that for mail attachments. Box app can do that here, probably via CFBundleDocumentTypes in plist. But is there a way to do that with e.g. photos?

[image: Box offers to open mail attachment]

Hopefully anybody can give me any useful links with examples of such implementation.

Thanks a lot

--Dannie

Comment: u want to add UIactivityIndicator to UIButton ??

Comment: nope, i want to add a button here to let user share photos to my server http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvMgt.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 6, there is no way to add a custom `UIActivity` item to built-in apps like Photos, Notes, or Safari.

Custom `UIActivity` items can only be added to third-party apps.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. Any prooflink for that?

Comment: The [UIActivityViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that its for offering various services from *your* application. There is no public API for adding custom `UIActivity`s as extensions to the built-in standard apps. But I'm crossing my fingers that Apple will add this to a future version of iOS.